# Select name of creator and editor from user table

Tags: mysql

How I can select name of creator and editor from `users` table, `creator` and `editor` are different ids in same table, but `user` table is different table

Comment: You're going to give more details about your schema. It would also be good if you showed us what you have already attempted.

Comment: yes. please at least show us what your tables looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you mean?

> $sql = "
>   SELECT id,name
>   FROM users
>   WHERE users.id = editors_table.$editor_id
>   OR users.id = creators_table.$creator_id";

Answer (score 0):

from what i understand, are you saying you have 3 tables - 1 with creator data, 1 with editor data, and a third that references a record in each of the tables using an id?

if so, you'll have to use JOINs to achieve what you want - something like:

```
SELECT id, name, editors_table.editor_id, creators_table.creator_id
FROM users
LEFT JOIN editors_table ON user.editor_id = editor_table.editor_id
LEFT JOIN creators_table ON user.creator_id = creator_table.creator_id
WHERE editor_table.editor_id = $editor_id_var
OR creator_table.creator_id = $creator_id_var
```

(you'll want to go through the query as I'm guessing here)